# Material UI MuiTheme Modification

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, material-ui

how do I modify MuiTheme in overrides if it has a name like this?

```
.MuiStepLabel-label.MuiStepLabel-active {
    color: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.87);
    font-weight: 500;
```

I've tried modifying MuiStepLabelLabel, root of it and many more, nothing works, trying to change the color, please help.

Comment: Open the code of any component example and you will see how they use `makeStyles` to override the default CSS.

Comment: it works with any other code, this one doesn't

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to modify it in Theme override, you can do something like this:

```
MuiStepLabel {
    label: {
        color: rgba(155, 0, 0, 0.87);
    }
}
```

And you can use it with `createMuiTheme`